# Raspberry Pi Ethernet network bridge with separate wireless connectivity

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3b+, wireless-adapter, systemd-networkd

As explained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100515/building-a-packet-squirrel-using-raspberry-pi), I built an Ethernet bridge using a Raspberry Pi 3b+.

As an extension, I am now trying to connect it to the internet via the WiFi interface.

For that I configured the wireless interface as shown [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). Then I brought the wireless interface up using `ifconfig wlan0 up`. When I run `ifconfig` I can see the **wlan0** interface in the list of interfaces (i.e. it's active). But it does not connect to a network.

I also noticed that when I make the changes provided in the first link, the complete networking capabilities (other than the bridge) of the RPi cease. (Although I am bridging only the two Ethernet interfaces)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In the setup you have linked there is no WiFi involved. This would add an additional interface that may conflict with the bridge. So what exactly have done?

Comment: After building the bridge, I configured the wireless interface as given [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).  Then I brought the interface up using  
    **ifconfig wlan0 up**.  
When I type **ifconfig** I can see the wlan0 interface active, but it doesn't connect to the network

Comment: Please add this information to your question. You can edit it. Then I will make an answer.

Comment: @Ingo I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have completely setup and running [Building a 'Packet squirrel" using Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100526/79866) you have linked in your question. It is using **systemd-networkd**. If you want to extend it with WiFi you also have to use *systemd-networkd*, in particular to use `*.network` configuration files. So try this and add setup *wpa_supplicant* in addition to the existing installation with your settings for `country=`, `ssid=` and `psk=` and enable it:

```
rpi ~# cat >/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf <<EOF
country=DE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    psk="verySecretMyPassword"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
EOF

rpi ~# chmod 600 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
rpi ~# systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service
rpi ~# systemctl enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

and then create this `*.network` file:

```
rpi ~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
# If you need a static ip address, then toggle commenting next four lines (example)
DHCP=yes
#Address=192.168.10.60/24
#Gateway=192.168.10.1
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
EOF
```

Reboot
and it should do.

Comment: After completing this step, the internet connectivity of the network where the bridge is connected (i.e., the network provided by the AP in the first question) is lost. Any idea why?

Comment: @Nht_e0 No, but I will test it. Just a moment please. What first question do you mean?

Comment: @Please take your time :). The question I have linked to this one

Comment: @Nht_e0 I have just setup my RPi 4B as described at [Building a 'Packet squirrel" using Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100526/79866) and with the extension from this answer. Everything works fine as expected. What is the different to your setup? Where does your setup does not match exactly my installation? To what destination do you connect with WiFi and wired? Is it the same router?

Comment: I did play around with the network settings sometime ago after setting up the bridge. Let me check this on a fresh install. 
As for the setup, I'm trying this on a RPi 3B+ (which I don't think is an issue). I tried to connect to connect to the same router

Comment: @Nht_e0 Using RPi 3B+ should also do. Connecting to the same router, onetime wired (the sniffed line), onetime by WiFi, is no problem as long as you don't give the bridge an ip address. But I don't understand your effort. Just giving the bridge an ip address as described in the setup has the same effect. You don't need WiFi. It only makes sense if you want to connect to another device than the router to manage the RasPi.

Comment: it worked after I tried it on a fresh install of Raspbian. As for the reason, I'm just playing around with this :) However, if you do give the bridge an IP address, doesn't it loose the capability to listen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97474/discussion-between-ingo-and-nht-e0).